# How can I call the div inside my JavaScript HTML so the map will be drawn on each post displayed on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-api-3

So this is a little complicated. I'm doing a university assignment using Firebase Firestore. Basically I have a page that displays information that is filled in on a separate page each entry into my database has a latitude and longitude value and I want to have a map on each entry that is displayed, so inside my JavaScript folder where I am writing HTML for how I want the info displayed I have the map div (I'm gonna use the doc.id for a unique identifier but for the time being I'm just trying to get the map working).

I'm getting this error

```
"Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null."
```

Which I presume is because it can't find my div so my question is how can I make it find the div?

```
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}

maleRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let hacks = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        hacks.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
    });
    // console.log(hacks);
    let html = ``;
    hacks.forEach(hacks => {        
        html += 
        `
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="item">
                <h4 id="itemName">${hacks.name}</h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img id="itemPhoto" src="${hacks.photo}">
                    </div>
                    <div id="itemInfo" class="col-8">
                        <p><b>Age:</b></p>
                        <p>${hacks.age}</p><br><br>
                        <p><b>Gender:</b></p>
                        <p>${hacks.gender}</p><br><br>
                        <p><b>Email:</b></p>
                        <p>${hacks.email}</p><br><br>
                        <p><b>Number:</b></p>
                        <p>${hacks.number}</p><br><br>
                        <p><b>Address:</b></p>
                        <p>${hacks.address}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width=80%; height: 200px;" id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
        document.querySelector('.maleContainer').innerHTML = html;
    
    });
});
```

This is the order I have the script links which I believe to be correct

```
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.4.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/8.4.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script src="js/permition.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you have multiple of those entries, the resulting HTML will be invalid.  The `id` must be unique.  The likely issue is that the translation of a string to a DOM element takes time and is typically executed asynchronously; so when the Google Map API tries to access it, it isn't in the DOM yet. Possible fixes: 1. create DOM elements and add them directly to the DOM 2. wait until the DOM has been updated before running the Google Maps Javascript API `Map` constructor.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of answering this question I'm gonna put what fixed it in the end. Credit to geocodezip who helped me figure it out. Basically as geocodezip said the map was initialising before the posts were being added so the map div didn't exist in order to solve that I removed the callback on my API link and then wrapped the map code in a function and called them at the end of the snapshot

```
maleRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let hacks = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        hacks.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
    });
    // console.log(hacks);
    let html = ``;
    hacks.forEach(hacks => {        
        html += 
        `
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="item">
                    <h4 id="itemName">${hacks.name}</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img id="itemPhoto" src="${hacks.photo}">
                        </div>
                        <div id="itemInfo" class="col-8">
                            <p><b>Age:</b></p>
                            <p>${hacks.age}</p><br><br>
                            <p><b>Gender:</b></p>
                            <p>${hacks.gender}</p><br><br>
                            <p><b>Email:</b></p>
                            <p>${hacks.email}</p><br><br>
                            <p><b>Number:</b></p>
                            <p>${hacks.number}</p><br><br>
                            <p><b>Address:</b></p>
                            <p>${hacks.address}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div style="400px; height: 200px;" id="${hacks.id}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        `
        document.querySelector('#maleContainer').innerHTML = html;
    });
    maleMap();
});

function maleMap() {
    maleRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let hacks = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            hacks.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
        });
        // console.log(hacks);
        hacks.forEach(hacks => {
            const myLatLng = {lat: +hacks.lat, lng: +hacks.lng};

            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(hacks.id), {
                center: myLatLng,
                zoom: 14,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            });
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map,
                title: "You Live Here!"
            })
        });
    });
}
```